# Connect uploaded file with related model with Strapi

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, strapi

I am using Strapi, Sqlite3 and React. 
I want to send a form with a file attached.

I have a Job model, which looks like this:

```
{
  "connection": "default",
  "collectionName": "jobs",
  "info": {
    "name": "job",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "comment": ""
  },
  "attributes": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "resume": {
      "model": "file",
      "via": "related",
      "plugin": "upload"
    },
    "jobcategory": {
      "model": "jobcategory",
      "via": "jobs"
    }
  }
}
```

I am sending text input with `submitCareer` method, and `uploadFile` for uploading:

```
export async function submitCareer(url, formValues) {
    try {
        const entries = await rootUrl.createEntry(url, formValues);
        return entries;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

export async function uploadFile(formValues) {
    try {
        const upload = await rootUrl.upload(formValues);
        return upload;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

This is the usage in my Career component:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("files", fileInput.current.files[0]);   

        submitCareer('jobs', values);

        uploadFile(formData);


        setValues({
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            resume: null
        })

        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

I get this response:

```
{
        "id": 66,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "jobcategory": null,
        "lname": null,
        "created_at": 1561988031279,
        "updated_at": 1561988031279,
        "resume": {}
    }
```

So, how can i connect resume with Job model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Linking model to a file

You must create process with to two steps:

1. Create `File` -> `POST /upload`.
2. Create `Jobs` with `id` from `FileResponse` -> `POST /jobs`.

Example:

```
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("files", fileInput.current.files[0]);
      resumeUploadFile = await uploadFile(formData);

      const jobsInput = {...jobs, ...{resume: resumeUploadFile.id}}
      await submitCareer('jobs', jobsInput);

      setValues({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        resume: null
      })

      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

[https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/upload.html#file-upload](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/upload.html#usage)

#### Linking files to an entry

You can linking too file to an entry wich is created, then you create first `Jobs` and then link upload `ResumeFile` with added new fields like `refId` from `Jobs` (`Jobs -> id`), `ref` in your case `jobs` and `field=resume`

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/upload.html#examples

Comment: I did it this way:  const jobData = await submitCareer('jobs', values); and appended jobs id on FormData:  formData.append('refId', jobData.id);

Answer (score 0):

When you want to upload a file and link it to an entry.
You have to first create the entry if it's not already done.
And then upload your file by sending the image information of the entry.

All the documentation is here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/upload.html#examples

Comment: I tried with refId, but I can't get to the Jobs model id which is autoincremented